# Tensorflow: How to prefetch data on the GPU from CPU tf.data.Dataset (from_generator)

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am struggling with the following. I am creating a tf.data.Dataset using the from_generator method. I perform these actions on CPU as I don't want to overload my GPU memory.

The dataset consists of tuples, which contain a tf.bool 1-D mask (tf.Tensor) with fixed length, and a tf.float 2-D matrix (tf.Tensor) with variable size. The loss function is decorated using the following decorator, so I would not assume the variable size is the problem.

```
@tf.function(experimental_relax_shapes=True)
```

Ideally, the dataset is kept on the CPU, but then prefetched onto the GPU.

```
        def gen():
            for i, j in zip(mask_list, wmat_list):
                yield i, j

        dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen, output_types=(tf.bool, tf.float32))
```

The main training loop currently relies on tf.identity to move the data to the gpu, which is inefficient. As shown on the screenshot from Tensorboard below. Roughly 70% of the time is spend loading the data and moving it to GPU.

```
                for b, (mask, wmat) in enumerate(dataset):
                    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:

                        mask = tf.identity(mask)
                        wmat = tf.identity(wmat)

                        mean_error, loss = self.model.loss(mask, wmat)
                        epoch_loss += loss.numpy()
                        epoch_mean_error += mean_error.numpy()
```

[image: Tensorboard tracing viewer]

I have tried the "prefetch_to_device" function. However, it did not move the data onto the GPU. As verified by printing e.g. mask.device in the training loop.

```
        gpu_transform = tf.data.experimental.prefetch_to_device('/gpu')
        dataset.apply(gpu_transform)
```

For me it resembles to this bug: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/30929 . However, it is marked as solved and is over a year old.

Running TF 2.3 using the official Docker image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution to my own question.

The problem was that the tuples in the dataset did **not** contain tf.Tensors, but numpy arrays. Therefore, the pipeline was probably limited by the functionality of py_func().

The screenshot below show that the pipeline does not block on the CPU. However there is still a considerable MemCpy. The prefetch_to_device() still does not do anything. This is likely due to a known issue which should be fixed in TF2.4

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35563

<s>The (unconfirmed) suggested workaround also did not work for me.</s> (see edit)

```
with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
    ds = ds.prefetch(1)
```

[image: Trace view]

EDIT:

I have further investigated this issue and filed a bug report. It does now seem that the suggested workaround does something, but not sure if it completely prefetches in time.
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/43905